# Duplication within Java classpath issue

Tags: java, classpath

I have a program that imports its required classes from a .jar source.

However I have also unzipped said .jar source in order to search its file directory to gather up class names for a list within the same program.

The problem is that the class ** appears more than once in the classpath, this is due to it being simultaneously in the bin and as a library. I need both elements for separate, yet equally code features.

I've found removing the file directory of the .jar source solves the problem however my list is now blank.

Anyone know of a way to do both?

Comment: so are you saying there is a class `com.hopeless.Foo` in both your application (therefore in bin or classes) as well as in a jar that it uses?  if yes, why do they have the same package naming?

Comment: You know you can get all the classnames without actually unzipping the JAR right?

Comment: @foampile yes, the package is from sourceforge so it's not my code, would altering the names mitigate the issue?

Comment: @Perception The program that runs is a simple file string array search. At the time it was the easiest way to find all the class names to gather them together.

Comment: why does your application follow the same package naming as something you got off sourceforge?  if you change your package pathing, you will solve the issue

Comment: @foampile ok sounds good, do I simply rename packages I've used and imported to resolve this?

Comment: yes.  see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you said above in the comments, if your package names start with `com.somethingfromsourceforge.*` then I would change `com.somethingfromsourceforge` to `com.hopeless` and the pathing issue should be resolved.  Try this and let us know.